# Countblank and ImportRange for Conditional Formatting Custom Function

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, reference, google-sheets-formula, gs-conditional-formatting

So I am trying to set up a conditional formatting custom function that will highlight the cell in question if a certain range on another spreadsheet contains any blank cells up to the last row of that spreadsheet. Can I write this as a formula for conditional formatting? Any help would be appreciated, thank you.

I tried:

```
=IF(COUNTBLANK(IMPORTRANGE(Index!$C9,"report.csv!E:F")))>0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when referencing another sheet in conditional formatting you need to use `INDIRECT()`

try:

```
=IF(COUNTBLANK(IMPORTRANGE(INDIRECT("Index!$C9"), "report.csv!E:F"))>0, 1)
```

Comment: Thank you for your help Player! So I should probably specify, that reference Index!$C9 is a file ID for another spreadsheet, can I reference other spreadsheets in the conditional formatting formula system?

Comment: @WarrenMeroney yes you can. see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59257893/5632629