# Custom Formula Conditional Formatting incorporating 2 spreadsheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, gs-conditional-formatting, importrange

Is it possible to arrange a conditional formatting custom formula based on information input into a different spreadsheet?

For example, I have 1 in A1, 2 in A2 and 3 in A3 on a spreadsheet saved as 'Numbers' and in a worksheet titled 'List' and in a spreadsheet saved as 'Input' I enter 1 in A1 of a worksheet titled 'Entry'. When I enter 1 in the 'Input' spreadsheet I would want cell A1 in the 'Numbers' spreadsheet to become highlighted.

I've had a play around with IMPORTRANGE AND IF formulae but to no avail

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
=A1=IMPORTRANGE("16nnuzNRx_kGGJm1EBVX7kBT2bfW1-2TYwSiuaLF-Q", "Numbers!A1:A")
```

that weird number is spreadsheet ID (you can find it in URL between `d/` and `/edit`)

[image: 0]

note that both ranges need to be formatted same

---

a faster alternative would be to use `IMORTRANGE` to import those values in some column and then just compare those two columns

Comment: Struggling to make that formula work but I have now completed the structure of my spreadsheet so can use more accurate information now. In my 'Master' spreadsheet I have a worksheet titled '390' and in cell X9 of this I have entered 69101. I require this cell to be highlighted via conditional formatting when I enter 69101 into any cell in the J column of a worksheet titled 'Haulage' within a spreadsheet titled 'Haulage'